# How to make grid Responsive Overlapping Content

Tags: html, css, grid, footer, responsive

Hello there i have made a grid for my website and the issue I am having is the grid overlaps the footer element I have been trying everything from setting the grid container to height Auto to see if it automatically adjusts I can't give it a set height as the website is responsive any help would be appreciated attached is my HTML and CSS code for the grid :)

```
    <html> 
<head> 
<link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/services-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="/aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>    
</div>    
</div>    
<div class="content">
<div class="title logo">
<h1>Logo's</h1>    
</div>

<div class="title">    
<h1>"Just a Glimpse of what we can do for you and your business"</h1>
    </div>
<div class="Grid1">   
<div class="Gallery1">
<a href="Images/logo1.jpg">
<img src="/Images/logo1.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%;">    
    </a>    
    </div>
<div class="Gallery1">
<a href="Images/logo2.png">
<img src="/Images/logo2.png"style="width:100%; height:100%;">    
    </a>    
    </div>
<div class="Gallery1">
<a href="Images/logo3.jpg">
<img src="/Images/logo3.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%;">    
    </a>    
    </div> 
    <div class="Gallery1">
<a href="Images/logo-grid3.jpg">
<img src="/Images/logo-grid3.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%;">    
    </a>    
    </div>

    <div class="Gallery1">
<a href="Images/logo-grid3.jpg">
<img src="/Images/logo-grid3.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%;">    
    </a>    
    </div>

    <div class="Gallery1">
<a href="Images/logo-grid3.jpg">
<img src="/Images/logo-grid3.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%;">    
    </a> 
    </div>

        <div class="Gallery1">
<a href="Images/logo-grid3.jpg">
<img src="/Images/logo-grid3.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%;">    
    </a>    
    </div>

    <div class="Gallery1">
<a href="Images/logo-grid3.jpg">
<img src="/Images/logo-grid3.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%;">    
    </a>    
    </div>

    <div class="Gallery1">
<a href="Images/logo-grid3.jpg">
<img src="/Images/logo-grid3.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%;">    
    </a>     

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
<div class="Footer-Nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="/aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>    
</footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is code from main styles for all pages

```
    .Gallery1{
 margin:5px;
float: left;
width:300px;
height:200px;
position:relative;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}


.Grid1{
max-width:945px;
position: relative;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top: 25px;
}

div.logo{
 margin-top: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-family: Monospace;
 padding: 5px;

}
div.Gallery1:hover{
border-color:#777;
}
.title{
position: relative;
text-align: center;
margin-top:25px;
font-family: Monospace;
}




@media screen and (max-width:928px){
div.Grid1 {
width:308px;
margin:0 auto;
 }

}
@media screen and (max-width:487px){
div.Gallery1{
width:100%;
 }
div.Grid1{
width:90%;
 }
.title{
 margin:25px;
 }

}
.Grid1{
height: auto;
position: relative;
}
.content{
height:100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}
```

Media Queries

```
    @media screen and (max-width:928px){
   div.Grid1 {
   width:308px;
   margin:0 auto;
   }

   }

   @media screen and (max-width:487px){
   div.Gallery1{
   width:100%;
   }
```

[image: Photo of Footer Issue]

Comment: you need to set `float:left` to the  `div` ,

Comment: hi what div are you referring to :)

Comment: grid , title , something like overlaping

Comment: hi there when I add float left to the content like title, grid it cause the content  to not be central alignment it may help of you bring code up in a environment to see what i mean :)

Comment: ok just remove the `float:left` and add `display:inline-block` and smaller device use `display:block`

Comment: hey, I have tried what you suggested I have also added an image of my browser to show you what is actually happening I have tried high auto but nothing is changing :)!

Answer (score 0):

just add float left to your footer and width 100%

```
footer{
width:100%;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: hey I tried what you suggested and the footer does go to the bottom of the page but the content is still overlapping slightly and when I resize the browser window and the grid panels change into a single line (via media queries) the content overlaps the footer completely :) really been strugling to get my head round :(

Comment: for content overlapping add marting-top or padding-top in footer style as per your overlapping

Comment: i need your media query style to check your problem and solve it. edit your question and add media query css

Comment: i add your media query to my file and it will work fine for me just put my above css code before your media query.

Comment: hey, i have tried what you suggested i have also added an image of my browser to show you what is actually happening really can't get my head around this one :) I have tried high auto but nothing is changing :)

Answer (score 0):

so I solved the issue I was having myself here is the snippet of code to where I solved the issue I basically had to recode my footer and added a height dimension to solve the issue if anyone is having this issue hope it helps :)

```
    Footer{
    width: 100%;
   height: 76px;
 background-color:#404040;
 margin-top: 76px;
}
.footer-nav{
width:403px;
height: 21px;
position: relative;
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-left:10px;
}
.footer-nav ul li{
display: block;
 float: left;
 padding-left:15px;
 padding-right:15px;
}
.footer-nav ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
color:white;
font-family:monospace;
font-size: 14px;
}
```